# my java swing form will not launch

Tags: java, swing, runnable

I had this form launching previously using this code but after several edits to the form it will no longer launch. Any suggestions?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  try {
    for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info: javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
      if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
        break;
      }
    }
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Registrar.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
  //</editor-fold>
  /* Create and display the form */
  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      new Registrar().setVisible(true);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: There are numerous possibilities why your application might not launch. Post an [sccee](http://sscce.org/) for better help sooner

Comment: I'm not sure what to trim because it says the project builds successfully

Comment: @TYGYR It would be great if you could show what `Registrar` class is and what it does. Is it a `JFrame` ? Or if your project is small, post it entirely.

Comment: @LittleChild is 1200 lines considered small in Java?

Comment: @TYGYR No, it is not in any language :D

Comment: @LittleChild didn't think so i'm working a final project for a class and i had it all going well until it stopped displaying the form. Its a JFrame with tabbed panels

Comment: @TYGYR Here is what I do, as a student, when stuff goes wrong. I take a piece of paper and write down, step-by-step, what is happening and see the values different variables contain. I compare this with what I was expecting :) Helps most of the time

Comment: @LittleChild is right; creating an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) from scratch is a way to pare the problem down to size and get the GUI editor out of your way. Also look in `Team > History` for when things went awry.

Answer (score 0):

Possible findings..

1. Use debug and find the the error.
2. Check default run from the project>properties>run and check default main class;
3. Remove all code and re-write main class;

Suggestion: There should be an error message. You should post that.